# Extended function jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-plugins

I have a function that looks like this:

```
jQuery.fn.menuFunc = function( settings ) {
        settings = jQuery.extend({ 
          actionAddURL:"",
          actionModifyURL:"",
          ........
          },settings);};
```

where all the parameters i initialize (actionAddURL, actionModifyURL, etc..) are strings (ids of different elements or urls). My question is how do i add some objects there.
myObject:""  doesn't seem to be the way to do it. Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
myObject:[] // empty JavaScript object
,
myOtherObject: { // JavaScript object notation
       name: "Bob",
       age: 17
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably:

```
myObject: {}
```

is what you are looking for.

You can then add properties to it:

```
myObject.name = "Name";
```

Answer (score 0):

To define an object you could use the following syntax:

```
myObject: { stringProp: 'value1', intProp: 10, arrayProp: [ 1, 2, 3 ] }
```